# Client API + Server Impl

Tags: java, web-services, oop

I have a question: how to implement correctly in Java late/dynamic binding. I have a situation, when client has API jar only (interfaces and abstract classes) and client wants to call server/service (via HTTP), where these interfaces are implemented. How architecturally it can be done? (i like servlet-api/servlet-impl example, and want the same...). Maybe any techniques are already presented?

Answer (score 0):

Java ALWAYS uses late binding. Or did you mean something else from the definition of late binding as it applies to compiled programming languages?

Comment: I would like on client to invoke an interface method - and on server it is actually processed, cause there is actual implementation. How it could be better done?